# The proper way of creating an array of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, libcurl, libpng

I ran into a problem when I was trying to modify a sample code. The sample code is very simple, it constantly fetches some .png files from the server using a curl_easy_handle. Then it calls the read_png_file() function from libpng to read the downloaded images.

Right now I am trying to modify this program by using curl_multi API to fetch multiple images at the same time. I can successfully download the images, but when I call read_png_file() it will return an error of "input not recognized as a PNG file".

The original program takes an input like this:

```
  png_bytep input_buffer = malloc(sizeof(png_byte)*BUF_SIZE);
  struct bufdata bd; 
  bd.buf = input_buffer;
  png_structp png_ptr;
  png_infop info_ptr;
  png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Then calls the function by:

```
png_bytep* row_pointers = read_png_file(png_ptr, &info_ptr, &bd);
```

What I have now is:

```
  png_structp png_ptr;
  png_infop info_ptr;
  png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
  png_bytep input_buffer[num_threads];
  struct bufdata bd[num_threads];
  for (int i=0; i<number; i++){
    input_buffer[i] = malloc(sizeof(png_byte)*BUF_SIZE);
    bd[i].buf = input_buffer[i]; 
  }
```

And then I call the function:

```
png_bytep* row_pointers = read_png_file(png_ptr, &info_ptr, &bd[i]);
```

Then in the read_png_file() function, it will fail at this line:

```
  if (png_sig_cmp(bd->buf, 0, 8))
    abort_("[read_png_file] Input is not recognized as a PNG file");
```

So I am assuming that the input &bd[i] is wrong, does anyone know what went wrong here? I have verified that the corresponding address of bd->buf and input_buffer is actually the same.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: clarification: is this line called for each .png file to be read or once by each thread? 'png_bytep* row_pointers = read_png_file(png_ptr, &info_ptr, &bd[i]);'   As far as the other end of the connection is concerned, this is all the same connection, so each returned item can/will go to (depending ony which thread gets control) a different input buffer.  Suggest generating a separate TCP connection for each file to be download that way each TCP connection will be handled by the appropriate thread.

Comment: The function `read_png_file()` is not part of the standard LibPNG library.  That makes it tricky to reproduce your problem — you've got issues in that function, but we can't see what that function is doing.  You don't initialize the `info_ptr` variable before passing it to your function; it is not possible for us to know whether that's safe or not, but there is room for doubt that it is safe.